# How can I make a new Column "Week" into a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My code is as follows:

```
my_dict = {
    "Date": pd.date_range('2020', freq='D', periods=100),
    "Open": np.random.randn(100),
    "High": np.random.randn(100),
    "Low": np.random.randn(100),
    "Close": np.random.randn(100),
    "Volume": np.random.randn(100),
}

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
display(df)
```

How can I add "Week" column and values like "2020-01", "2020-02"?

"2020-01" means the first week of 2020.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the year using dt year attribute and concatenate with week attribute. *zfill* is to fill leading zeros.

```
(df['Date'].dt.year.astype(str)
     .str.cat(df['Date'].dt.week.astype(str).str.zfill(2),
              sep='-'))

    0     2020-01
    1     2020-01
    2     2020-01
    3     2020-01
    4     2020-01
           ...   
    95    2020-14
    96    2020-15
    97    2020-15
    98    2020-15
    99    2020-15
```

Comment: Hello, Can I use your function for random dates?

Comment: In the example you posted, the date column is a datetime object. So, you can directly use dt and get the required data. If it is not a datetime object, you have to convert to date time object. Also, if the day of the month is not present in the date column, you cannot get the week

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
In [2233]: df['Week'] = df.Date.dt.year.astype(str) + '-' + df.Date.dt.week.astype(str).map(lambda x: f'{x:0>2}')

In [2234]: df.Week
Out[2234]: 
0     2020-01
1     2020-01
2     2020-01
3     2020-01
4     2020-01
       ...   
95    2020-14
96    2020-15
97    2020-15
98    2020-15
99    2020-15
Name: Week, Length: 100, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hello, Can I use your function for random dates?

Comment: Yes, it can be used for random dates as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following:

```
df["Week"] = 1
df["Week"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.to_period('M')
```

dt.to_period takes value M/Y/D to print month year and date respectively

Comment: I don think this is the expected output. OP wants the exact week number for the year, not the `year-month` combination.

Answer (score 0):

use `datetime`. I am using pandas `.apply()` and a `lambda` function to get the week formatted.

Since the 'Date' columns is made of timestamp class objects, `isocalendar()` function returns a tuple `('year','week','day')` which is formatted to the way you want.

```
import datetime
df['Week']=df['Date'].apply(lambda x: "{0}-{1:02d}".format(*list(x.isocalendar())))
df.head(10)
```

output:

> 

```
Date    Open    High    Low Close   Volume  Week
0   2020-01-01  -0.628361   -0.019378   0.167120    1.421006    -0.698276   2020-01
1   2020-01-02  -0.515597   0.467128    1.784242    0.358433    0.197478    2020-01
2   2020-01-03  0.781038    0.225310    -0.636053   -0.241801   0.777247    2020-01
3   2020-01-04  1.332335    0.687737    -0.531952   1.554296    -0.243784   2020-01
4   2020-01-05  0.457940    -1.488220   0.408476    -0.196996   -0.970725   2020-01
5   2020-01-06  1.660737    0.610343    -0.769449   -0.854537   -1.203444   2020-02
6   2020-01-07  -0.472873   0.276941    -0.266524   0.450023    1.260696    2020-02
7   2020-01-08  -0.851558   0.092650    0.207837    0.107786    -0.002486   2020-02
8   2020-01-09  0.967156    0.337234    -1.394543   -0.221563   1.231157    2020-02
9   2020-01-10  0.407043    -1.079271   -0.730196   -0.262280   0.367848    2020-02
```